# is this pseudoreplication?

Tags: inference

I'm sampling 5 different fields using transects. I'd like to gauge soil moisture and how it varies based on each field. If I choose five pre-determined points within each field and then take their data as 5 REPLICATES, could I then run a mixed effect model with field as a random effect and use the replicates as individual, independent points? I'm not interested in the field identity all that much as an explanatory variable, I Just want to account for it.

I.e. each field would have n = 5 samples, not n = 1 averasged sample.

Or , is this pseudoreplication, because they are all coming from the same field?